# PHP - Pegando valores de uma tabela HTML e inserindo em tabela MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, table

Possuo uma tabela que é resultado de uma consulta MySQL de um banco em um servidor. Ela é mostrada da seguinte forma, por exemplo:

```
E-MAIL  VALUE
------  -----
email1  P
email2  P
email3  C
email4  P
email5  C
email6  P
```

Preciso que na minha página (que está num outro servidor que não o da página onde está essa tabela) ele possa pegar o valor da segunda coluna (P ou C) quando o usuário loga com um dos e-mails dessa tabela.

Supondo então que o usuário seja o do email5, ele tem de pegar o valor C. Depois de pegar o valor C, esse valor será inserido numa outra tabela (de banco MySQL) do servidor da minha página.

Não sei se ficou muito claro. Minha ideia inicial era pegar valor de uma tabela de um banco MySQL (do servidor 1) e colocar na outra tabela de outro banco MySQL (do servidor 2), mas até agora não obtive sucesso.

Provavelmente a função terá que ser em javascript. Mas se puder ser feita em PHP seria melhor.

**EDITADO - O código que tentei com acesso rápido aos dois bancos:**

```
$emailInv = $this->email;
$sqlNuevo = "SELECT DISTINCT uh.TIPO_INVESTIDOR FROM ipi_tst.uh
            JOIN ipi_tst.investidor i ON i.ID = uh.ID_INVESTIDOR
            JOIN ipi_tst.usuario u ON u.ID = i.ID_USUARIO
            WHERE u.EMAIL = '$emailInv' AND u.ID <> 0 ORDER BY FIELD(TIPO_INVESTIDOR,'P','C','O','A')";

$conn = new mysqli("201.7.201.173", "ipi_tst", "ipi_tst", "ipi_tst");
$rNew = $conn->query($sql);

if ($rNew[0]['TIPO_INVESTIDOR'] == 'O'){
    $sqlUpd = "UPDATE b2c.investidor SET office = '1' WHERE email = '$emailInv' AND ID <> 0";
    $res = System::element('db')->query($sqlUpd);
}
else if ($rNew[0]['TIPO_INVESTIDOR'] == 'A'){
    $sqlUpd = "UPDATE b2c.investidor SET office = '2' WHERE email = '$emailInv' AND ID <> 0";
    $res = System::element('db')->query($sqlUpd);
}
else {
    $sqlUpd = "UPDATE b2c.investidor SET office = '0' WHERE email = '$emailInv' AND ID <> 0";
    $res = System::element('db')->query($sqlUpd);
} 
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Você tem acesso aos dois bancos? Do servidor 1 e 2? Se sim você pode fazer tudo em PHP. Se você só tiver acesso ao HTML gerado da tabela do servidor 1, você tera que pegar o valor via javascript. Baseado nisso, faça uma tentativa e poste o código para que possamos ajudar melhor.

Comment: o título leva a uma interpretação muito diferente do contexto.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Sim, eu tenho acesso aos dois bancos. Vou editar o post e pôr o código que tentei, mais próximo de uma simples conexão MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Descobri a solução, amigos. Eu estava usando comandos que começavam com mySqli e, provavelmente, era esse o problema. O código que funcionou ficou assim:

```
                    $emailInv = $this->email;
                    $sqlNuevo = "SELECT DISTINCT uh.TIPO_INVESTIDOR FROM ipi_tst.uh
                    JOIN ipi_tst.investidor i ON i.ID = uh.ID_INVESTIDOR
                    JOIN ipi_tst.usuario u ON u.ID = i.ID_USUARIO
                    WHERE u.EMAIL = '$emailInv' AND u.ID <> 0 ORDER BY FIELD(TIPO_INVESTIDOR,'P','C','O','A') LIMIT 1";

                    $dbhandle = mysql_select_db("ipi_tst",mysql_connect("201.7.201.173", "ipi_tst", "ipi_tst"));
                    $resultNovo = mysql_query($sqlNuevo);
                    //$conn = new mysqli("201.7.201.173", "ipi_tst", "ipi_tst", "ipi_tst");
                    //$rNew = $conn->query($sql);
                    //$rNew = System::element('db2')->query($sqlNuevo);

                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultNovo)) {
                        $rNew = $row{'TIPO_INVESTIDOR'};
                    }

                    if ($rNew == 'O'){
                        $sqlUpd = "UPDATE b2c.investidor SET office = '1' WHERE email = '$emailInv' AND ID <> 0";
                        $res = System::element('db')->query($sqlUpd);
                    }
                    else if ($rNew == 'A'){
                        $sqlUpd = "UPDATE b2c.investidor SET office = '2' WHERE email = '$emailInv' AND ID <> 0";
                        $res = System::element('db')->query($sqlUpd);
                    }
                    else {
                        $sqlUpd = "UPDATE b2c.investidor SET office = '0' WHERE email = '$emailInv' AND ID <> 0";
                        $res = System::element('db')->query($sqlUpd);
                    }
                    mysql_close($dbhandle);
```